# How to find field variables to pass to URL for custom button?

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking

I've seen several solutions for passing variables via a URL string.
I'm just wondering how you can find these variables.
For example, there are some that have explained as below.
I'm trying to find the 'Call Type' variable on a task to pass in the URL string.
This one listed below is for just 'Type'.

Type: &tsk10={!text} (The text you type in here must be a value in the picklist)

example string:
https://na6.salesforce.com/00T/e?title=Call&who_id=!User.Id}&00N800000004wDKu=Marketing&what_id={!Account.Id}&tsk3=!Account.Name}&tsk5=Call&tsk12=Completed&retURL=%2F{Account.Id}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a chrome browser right click and say inspect element.

Say for eg. you want to include the name of the field "website" for using in your URL param

Right click on the website input field and you should the screen split into half and show the raw code like

```
<div id="acc12_ileinner" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Use the Id in your URL acc12_ileinner= "yahoo.com"

Comment: Or most *any* modern browser. Opera, Firefox, and even IE all have F12 tools these days (or at least enough to get at ID values).